# CFWheels - How to highight which posts a user has commented on?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I have a basic query to get all 'posts' in my database table 'posts'. Users who are logged in can comment on these posts. However, I want to be able to highlight (when viewing all posts) which ones the user has commented on before.

My query at the moment looks like this:

```
<cfset posts = model("post").findAll(

            select = "

                posts.postID,
                postTitle,
                postPoints,
                postAuthority,
                postCreated,
                postDescription,

                postCommentCount,
                postUpVoteCount,
                postDownVoteCount,

                users.userID,
                userName,

                categories.categoryID,
                categoryTitle,
                categoryToken",

            include     = "user,category", 
            order       = "postPoints DESC",
            page        = params.page,
            perPage     = params.pageQuantity

        ) />
```

I get all posts and join the user who created the post along with the category info etc.

How can I modify this, so that if the user is logged in, they'll be able to see which posts they've already commented on? The amount of comments the user has made isn't that important, just if the user has commented at all.

I'd prefer not to run a query on every post to check this. Ideally, it'd be good to join the count in with this query.

In addition to this, I have 3 queries in the posts model:

```
 <cfset property(name="postUpVoteCount", sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.postID = posts.postID AND votes.voteType = 1") />
        <cfset property(name="postDownVoteCount", sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.postID = posts.postID AND votes.voteType = 0") />
        <cfset property(name="postCommentCount", sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.postID = posts.postID AND comments.commentRemoved = 0") />
```

Could I utilise that in my query?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Comment: Compare the logged in user_id to the user_id in the query then highlight if they match.

Comment: Agreed with @MattBusche. You should have your CFML evaluate this when generating the HTML, not the DB.

Comment: I can't do it simply at the CFML level, because this is a list of posts created by everyone, not just the person logged in. In the general posts query, there is no way to know if he / she logged in has comment on said post unless I do a look-up in the database to the comments table in a calculated property. Is there a better way?